# Dispose the dialog box from back command

Tags: codenameone

I've a dialog box which I want dispose by from back command as well. But it is not happening. Why is it?

```
selectDialog = new Dialog();
selectDialog.showPacked(BorderLayout.CENTER, false);
selectDialog.setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(true);

//why doesn't following code dispose dialog box?
Command back = new Command("") {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        if (selectDialog != null) {
            System.out.println("beck");
            selectDialog.dispose();
        }
    }
};
setBackCommand(back);
```

Comment: can you share the complete class code...if possible...

Comment: I've lots of code in this class which are irrelevant to the question. Just add it in a form & add some components to dialog will work eg Label test = new Label("test"); selectDialog.add(test);  And dialog box is inside actionlistener of a button

Comment: can you watch my reply on waiting for the JDialog result, where I have used an undecorated JDialog model, and thus after setting the result, it will close it self inside button click event, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116916/how-to-wait-the-answer-of-a-jdialog/48118541#48118541 hope it will help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
setBackCommand(back);
```

Use:

```
selectDialog.setBackCommand(back);
```